# How to get OS dark/light setting in Chrome Extension MV3 background js?

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In MV2, it's quite easy because there's a `background.html` concept, so that I can access `window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches` to understand the OS's theme setting.

But in MV3, the `background.html` is gone and in the `background.js`, if you retrieve that value, it will display the following error:

```
> window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches; 
Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @.....
```

Is there anything I can do?

The reason I want to achieve this is to set a observer in the background script to check the OS theme changing, so that I can update the extension icon accordingly to make sure it's perfectly matching the OS style.

Thanks for any kind of tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### 1. Make the initial check using the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/):

manifest.json:

```json
  "permissions": ["offscreen", "storage"],
```

background.js

```js
(async () => {
  await chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
    url: 'offscreen.html',
    reasons: ['MATCH_MEDIA'],
    justification: '!',
  }).catch(() => {});
  setDarkTheme(await chrome.runtime.sendMessage('checkDarkTheme'));
  chrome.offscreen.closeDocument();
})();

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg === 'darkThemeChanged') {
    setDarkTheme(msg.data);
  }
});

function setDarkTheme(val) {
  chrome.storage.session.set({isDark: val});
  // do something meaningful e.g. change the icon 
}
```

offscreen.html:

```html
<script src=offscreen.js></script>
```

offscreen.js:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg === 'checkDarkTheme') {
    sendResponse(matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches);
  }
});
```

##### 2. Observe the change in a script for a visible page

Browsers don't report it in invisible pages like MV2 background page or the offscreen document. This means that you won't receive any notification until a visible page is opened.

You'll need to declare a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) for `<all_urls>`, which adds "Reads data on all sites" permission warning when installing the extension.

content.js:

```js
{
  const mq = matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
  const cb = async evt => {
    const { isDark } = await chrome.storage.session.get('isDark');
    if (isDark !== evt.matches) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        cmd: 'darkThemeChanged',
        data: evt.matches,
      });
    }
  };
  mq.onchange = cb;
  cb(mq);
}
```

You should also include this code block in your extension pages (but not the entire content.js which is meant for web pages) so that the detection occurs when your extension page or popup is opened in a browser that doesn't have any tabs with web pages where you content.js runs.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed instruction. This is so nice. I would like to ask for one more  thing, will the offscreen/storage permission cause the users being asked to consent accept or decline when install the extension?

Comment: No, it has no warning. You can test it as [described in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/permission-warnings#update-tool).

Comment: Do you think there's any bad affection by adding scripts to every page? I have been thinking this for a long time and still worried that injecting scripts on every page would be a bad practice for our users. Thanks

Comment: Not great, not terrible. Rather bad though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just wondering, is there any open issue for Chrome team about enabling dark theme icons? I think it is a quite graceful implementation to enable this officially rather than injecting content scripts to every page I browser.